# Using substack in flalign/align environment

Tags: equations, align, substack

I am using flalign environment for some summations which have substacks, however this seems to be giving me an "Undefined control sequence" error. Everything still compiles fine so it's not a huge deal but I would like to know if there is any way to fix this error.

```
    \begin{flalign}
        &\bigcup_{k=1}^{n+1}A_{k} - A_{n+1} = \bigcup_{k=1}^{n}A_{k} - A_{n+1} 
        =\bigcup_{k=1}^{n}A_{k} - A_{n+1}\cap\bigcup_{k=1}^{n}A_{k} &\\
        &P[\bigcup_{k=1}^{n+1}A_{k}] - P[A_{n+1}] =
        P[\bigcup_{k=1}^{n}A_{k}] - P[A_{n+1}\cap\bigcup_{k=1}^{n}A_{k}] \tag{finite additivity}&\\
        P[\bigcup_{k=1}^{n+1}A_{k}] &=
        P[\bigcup_{k=1}^{n}A_{k}] + P[A_{n+1}] - P[A_{n+1}\cap\bigcup_{k=1}^{n}A_{k}] &\\
        &= P[\bigcup_{k=1}^{n}A_{k}] + P[A_{n+1}] - P[\bigcup_{k=1}^{n}(A_{n+1}\cap A_{k})] &\\
        &= \sum_{\substack{T\subseteq [n] \\ T\neq \emptyset}}(-1)^{(|T|+1)}P[\bigcap_{t\in T}A_t]
        + P[A_{n+1}]
        - \sum_{\substack{T\subseteq [n] \\ T\neq \emptyset}}(-1)^{(|T|+1)}P[\bigcap_{t\in T}A_{n+1}\cap A_t] \\
        &= \sum_{\substack{T\subseteq [n+1]\\ A_{n+1}\notin T \\ T\neq \emptyset}}(-1)^{(|T|+1)}P[\bigcap_{t\in T}A_t]
        + \sum_{\substack{T\subseteq [n+1] \\ A_{n+1}\in T \\ T\neq \emptyset}}(-1)^{(|T|+1)}P[\bigcap_{t\in T} A_t] \\
        &= \sum_{\substack{T\subseteq [n+1] \\ T\neq \emptyset}}(-1)^{(|T|+1)}P[\bigcap_{t\in T}A_t]
    \end{flalign}
```

Removing all substacks gets rid of the errors.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Does your document load the `amsmath` package in the preamble?  (The `amsmath` package defines the `flalign` environment and the `\substack` macro.)

Comment: Please extend your code fragment to complete small document beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. Source of your problem may be in your document preamble.

Answer (score 2):

Your code compiles on my system (MacTeX2021) *if* I make sure to load the `amsmath` package. That's the package that defines the `flalign` (short for "full length align") environment and the `\substack` macro.

That said, I don't think that your equations make good use of the machinery of the `flalign` environment. (In fact, I'd go as far as claim that they make no use at all of that machinery.) For your equations, using a simple `align` environment, with one `&` alignment point per row, would make far more sense. Oh, and don't forget to enlarge the `[` and `]` square brackets if they enclose a `\bigcup` or `\bigcap` expression.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\bigcup_{k=1}^{n+1}A_{k} - A_{n+1} 
  &= \bigcup_{k=1}^{n}A_{k} - A_{n+1} 
   =\bigcup_{k=1}^{n}A_{k} - A_{n+1}\cap\bigcup_{k=1}^{n}A_{k} \\
P\Bigl[\,\bigcup_{k=1}^{n+1}A_{k}\Bigr] - P[A_{n+1}] 
  &= P\Bigl[\,\bigcup_{k=1}^{n}A_{k}\Bigr] 
   - P\Bigl[A_{n+1}\cap\bigcup_{k=1}^{n}A_{k}\Bigr] 
  \tag{finite additivity}\\
P\Bigl[\,\bigcup_{k=1}^{n+1}A_{k}\Bigr] 
  &= P\Bigl[\,\bigcup_{k=1}^{n}A_{k}\Bigr] + P[A_{n+1}] 
    - P\Bigl[A_{n+1}\cap\bigcup_{k=1}^{n}A_{k}\Bigr] \\
  &= P\Bigl[\,\bigcup_{k=1}^{n}A_{k}\Bigr] + P[A_{n+1}] 
    - P\Bigl[\,\bigcup_{k=1}^{n}(A_{n+1}\cap A_{k})\Bigr] \\
  &= \sum_{\substack{T\subseteq [n] \\ T\neq\emptyset}}
     (-1)^{(|T|+1)}P\Bigl[\,\bigcap_{t\in T}A_t\Bigr]
        + P[A_{n+1}] \notag \\
  &\qquad- \sum_{\substack{T\subseteq [n] \\ T\neq\emptyset}}
     (-1)^{(|T|+1)}P\Bigl[\,\bigcap_{t\in T}A_{n+1}\cap A_t\Bigr] \\
  &= \sum_{\substack{T\subseteq [n+1]\\ A_{n+1}\notin T \\ T\neq\emptyset}}
     (-1)^{(|T|+1)}P\Bigl[\,\bigcap_{t\in T}A_t\Bigr] \notag \\
  &\qquad+ \sum_{\substack{T\subseteq [n+1] \\ A_{n+1}\in T \\ T\neq\emptyset}}
     (-1)^{(|T|+1)}P\Bigl[\,\bigcap_{t\in T} A_t\Bigr] \\
  &= \sum_{\substack{T\subseteq [n+1] \\ T\neq\emptyset}}
     (-1)^{(|T|+1)}P\Bigl[\,\bigcap_{t\in T}A_t\Bigr]
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I realized the issue was somewhere else in my document even though for some it went away when I deleted the substacks. Thanks for the other tips though.